# Angular variable not displaying as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm sure this is something relatively simple, but I'm not seeing it at this hour, so I'm hoping someone else will.

Here's my relevant HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="/">
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body ng-app="LKSU">

...

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="main-content" ng-controller="HomeController">

<div class="attorney" ng-repeat="attorney in attorneys">
   {{attorney.name}} 
</div>

</div>
</div>

<!-- Modules -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="js/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>

<!-- Services -->
<script src="js/services/attorneys.js"></script>

<br clear="all" />

</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('LKSU', []);
```

attorneys.js

```
app.factory('attorneys', ['$http', function($http) { 
return $http.get('/js/services/attorneys.json') 
        .success(function(data) { 
          return data; 
        }) 
        .error(function(err) { 
            alert(err);         
          return err; 
        }); 
}]);
```

HomeController.js

```
app.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'attorneys',   function($scope, attorneys) {
attorneys.success(function(data){
    $scope.attorneys = data; 
    console.log($scope.attorneys);                             

});
}]);
```

When I look at the console in Chrome, the JSON data has made it across, but nothing displays when I loop through it. I really want to eventually limit by the ID number, but I figured let me just loop through first to make sure it's there, but it's not showing up.

I'm figuring that it must be how I'm calling the ng-repeat since I've verified that the data is sitting in $scope.attorneys.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

here's the JSON

```
{"attorneys":
[
{
"id":1,
"name":"Mitchell B. Goldberg",
"position":"Partner",
"piclink": "images/Mitch.jpg",
"quotes":
    [
     {
        "id": 1,
        "quote": "Wonderful guy!",
        "person": "Dovie"
     },
     {
        "id": 2,
        "quote": "If ye be wanting a haggis like no other, Mitchell be yer man!",
        "person": "Angus McLoed"
     },
     {
        "id": 3,
        "quote": "Wotta Hottie!",
        "person": "Natasha"
     }
     ],
"bio": "<p>Mitchell B. Goldberg, who started with Lawrence Kamin in 2001, focuses his practice on commercial litigation, concentrating in securities and commodity futures law and alternative dispute resolution. He is also a trained mediator.</p><p>His reputation for keeping the \"big picture\" in mind, rather than focusing solely on the individual case or issue before him, recently helped a large client with multiple FINRA arbitration claims that all had the same arbitrator as a panelist, but were not all represented by Lawrence Kamin. When that panelist ruled negatively in Mitch's case, Mitch contemplated bringing a motion to strike the arbitrator under FINRA guidelines prohibiting panelists from serving on multiple cases involving the same respondents. Even though this would have substantially advanced his own case, he instead suggested a conference call with all of the client's outside attorneys handling the remaining arbitrations to determine a joint strategy that would provide the biggest benefit to the mutual client. Ultimately the motion to strike was successfully brought in the case most likely to benefit.</p><p>He is also well-respected for his integrity, honesty and candor, which have earned him the trust of many judges and opposing counsel. This strength has often allowed Mr. Goldberg to achieve consensus in cases where other people wouldn't be able to achieve an agreement. For example, in one matter, distrust among the attorneys and parties resulted in a refusal of the plaintiffs to even discuss settlement. Mitch stepped in and, due to the opposing attorney's mutual respect, helped negotiate a settlement satisfactory to both sides.</p><p>Mitch's active membership on the boards of various legal committees and law societies, including the Chicago Bar Association and the Decalogue Society of Lawyers, reinforces his intent to continually improve the legal profession, as well as his desire to provide the best possible guidance to clients by keeping abreast of the latest developments in the law. Mitch has lectured to the Decalogue Society of Lawyers and taught securities litigation at IIT's Chicago-Kent College of Law with other members of the firm.</p><p>When not working for clients, serving on various boards or teaching, Mitch loves spending time with his wife Natasha and their four beautiful children, Rachel, Zachary, Jesse and Abigale.</p>",
"email": "mgoldberg@lksu.com",
"fax": "312.372.2389",
"phone":"312.924.4263",
"areas": ["altdispute", "litigation", "securities"],
"experience": "Lawrence, Kamin, Saunders & Uhlenhop LLC<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Partner: 2007-Present<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Associate: 2001-2007<br/><br/>Blau & Bonavich, 1999-2001",
"education": "DePaul University, J.D., with honor, 1999<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<em>Order of the Coif</em><br/><br/>DePaul University, B.A., highest honor, 1996",
"honors": "2008 - 2010, 2012 - 2014<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Rising Star in Securities Litigation,<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Super Lawyers  Magazine<br/><br/>2011 Decalogue Award of Excellence<br/><br/>2011 DePaul 14 under 40",
"articles": "Y",
"bar_admissions": "State ofIllinois",
"court_admissions": "United States District Courts<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Northern District of Illinois<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Seventh Circuit Court of Appeals",
"memberships": "Chicago Bar Association<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Co-Chair, ADR Committee, 2005-2007<br/><br/>Chicago Lincoln Inn of Court<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Pupilage Co-Chair, 2006-2010<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mentoring VP, 2012-Present<br/><br/>National Inns of Court<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Illinois State Liaison, 2009-Present<br/><br/>Decalogue Society of Lawyers<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Board of Managers, 2006-Present<br/><br/>DePaul University College of Liberal Arts & Sciences Deans Advisory Board, Vice Chair<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2010 to present"
}

]
}
```

Comment: You mean that the `ng-repeat` isn't showing anything? What does your JSON look like?

Comment: plain old JSON. I validated it and everything. And, yes, there is a name field. The ng-repeat just doesn't show anything.  Interestingly enough, when I put in a test "hello" next to the angular variable, I see it show up once. Which seems to imply that even at that point, it sees the object.

Comment: The problem appears to be how your `attorneys` factory is called and its return value. I'd probably make the factory return a function, ie `return function() { return $http.get ... }` then you can call `attorneys().then(function(data) { ... })` in your controller

Comment: @ReverendDovie No, I mean what does it actually look like? Can you show us?

Comment: I'd also remove the `success` and `error` callbacks from the factory and leave them for the controller

Comment: But why go through all that? The object makes it across and into my local object. I verified that. It seems like a lot of extra steps to make it into a function. Unless I'm missing something in your explanation.

Comment: @ReverendDovie The `success` callback in your factory is completely redundant, but I disagree that you should return a function. I think a promise is just fine.

Comment: The problem is, when is the `$http` call made? The answer is, when the factory is created. The way you have it, you can only use it once and even then, I'm not sure if it will work properly

Comment: I added the JSON. I also tested this with having the calls made at the top of the file, with no better results.

Comment: @Phil I'm not sure what you're trying to say. It's a static .json file, so why would OP want to retrieve it more than once?

Comment: @JLRishe I had thought the returned promise wouldn't be re-usable but it appears I'm wrong. I'm just more used to dealing with dynamic data where you would want to execute the AJAX request at call time

Comment: @Phil You can call chaining methods on promises as many times as you want. That's one of their main characteristics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array of attorneys is on an `.attorneys` property in your JSON data, and you are not accessing that. You're assigning the whole object to `$scope.attorneys`.

You need to access the array, so you can iterate over that:

```
app.controller('HomeController', [
    '$scope', 
    'attorneys',   
    function($scope, attorneys) {
        attorneys.success(function(data){
            $scope.attorneys = data.attorneys;   // <-- here
            console.log($scope.attorneys);                             
        });
    }
]);
```

If you do that, all should be well.

Comment: This, of course, leads to another question, but I'll post that as a new post.